# Open and closedness in a topology

Tags: general-topology

For fixed $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and any $b\in\mathbb{N}$, let $N_{a,b}=\{a+bn\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $\mathfrak{N}_a=\{N : \exists b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $N_{a,b}\subset N \}$

I have verified that $\mathfrak{N}_a$ gives a topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ (I think)

I am asked to verify that if $\mathcal{T}=\mathfrak{N}_a$, then the set $N_{a,b}$ is both open and closed in $(\mathbb{Z},\mathcal{T})$ for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ and any $b\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm used to working in metric spaces but new to thinking about things in topological spaces.

What I feel inclined to do is show that both the set in question and its compliment are open, but not sure how to do that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3587687/4280).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathfrak{N}_a$ actually isn’t a topology on $\Bbb Z$, because it doesn’t contain the empty set, but $\mathfrak{N}_a\cup\{\varnothing\}$ is a topology on $\Bbb Z$.

The sets $N_{a,b}$ are open by definition, but they are not in fact closed. You can prove this most easily by proving that their complements are not open. HINT: Every non-empty open set in this space contains $a$.

Comment: Well now I'm utterly confused becuase I was asked to show $N_{a,b}$ is both open and closed, as it is part of a larger proof for infinite primes.

Comment: @BenMorine: Are you sure that you’ve correctly stated the definition of the topology?

Comment: No I'm not. Actually I think what I've verified is that there exists a unique topology on Z such that $\mathfrak{N}_a=\mathcal{N}_a$

Comment: @BenMorine: Did you perhaps mean the topology described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evenly_spaced_integer_topology)?

Comment: yes that is the one.

Comment: @BenMorine: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes#Furstenberg's_proof) has a proof that the sets $N_{a,b}$ are both open and closed.

Comment: Thank you Brian its appreicated.

Comment: @BenMorine: You’re welcome.